# TCPDF when viewing in browser only displays one page

Tags: wordpress, pdf, tcpdf

Hi I have developed a wordpress site and noticed that when I visit PDF using this link: https://peppyplates.brookstonesites.co.uk/wp-content/fancy_products_orders/pdfs/74089_2.pdf

you are only able to see one page. If I then go into my file system and download the PDF it contains 5 pages. All 5 pages are duplicates I doubt this is an issue but thought it was worth mentioning.

When I visit the above link I want it to show all 5 pages. I'm not sure what is causing this issue. TCPDF is clearly creating the PDF correctly since when I download it the content is correct.

Could this be a wordpress issue and if so is there a fix because I don't want to have to go through the file system to get the file I need.

I am using a plugin called Fancy Product Designer to create the PDF, I have slightly modified it to add the duplicate pages which has worked a treat if I download the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

It was a wordpress caching issue. I myst have created the PDF before adding the code to duplicate the pages. I created a new order downloaded the PDF and it contains the duplicate pages.

NOTE TO SELF: always clear server cache if there is no reason for the issue ;)